# How to parse xlsb using perl or python

Tags: python, perl

I need to parse some information from a series of .xlsb files. I have used perl to parse ".xls" or ".xlsx" files, but didn't find any solutions for ".xlsb". Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

.xslb files are binary excel files, I believe stored in binary format so they can be opened faster(?).  I've had good success with the [Spreadsheet::Read](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Spreadsheet-Read-0.47/Read.pm) module, for regular Excel files, but I'm not confident you'll find a way to read a binary file and make any sense of it.